# Project references itself?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, circular-reference

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains a number of projects, most of which build fine.  However, one C# dll, called `Presentation.dll`, won't build, and a number of other projects reference it.

When I attempt to do so, I receive the following error:

[image: presentation.dll cannot be found]

As you can see, it appears that `Presentation.dll` depends on itself.  However, it does not appear in the references list, and there are not any other circular references that I can find.

If I grab `Presentation.dll` from a previous deployment into the directory with the executables and unload the Presentation project, the other dependent projects build fine, but if I have both the copied dll file and the project loaded, I get a number of Conflicting type errors:

[image: Conflicting type error]

I have searched the contents of `Presentation.csproj`, and there is no indication that it depends on itself.  I also tried marking all the conflicting types as `internal` as suggested by an answer to a question regarding that error, but that caused many more build errors.

What else should I be looking at?

Comment: Maybe Presentation.dll references a project which then references Presentation.dll again?

Comment: Try, Right click in your DLL go to: "Copy Local" set to True.

Comment: Clean solution and rebuild. If error persists, use file explorer to scan solution folder for any artifacts of the given file and check corresponding projects if they reference the library direct by file and not by project.